# PHP/MySQL Propel join with does not hydrate objects

Tags: php, mysql, join, propel

We are using Propel (1.7) for PHP. And I have some problems with hydrating joined objects.

Here is an example:

```
Table A
-------- 
id
anyColumn

Table B
-------- 
id
a_id
```

With propel I'm querying for objects from `Table A`, but want to (left) join the entries from `b`.

The query looks like:

```php
$as = AQuery::create()->filterByAnyColumn(anyValue)->leftJoinWithB()->find();
```

I outputted the mysql query and it looks good. I also called the query manually and all columns from b where there too. So everything looks good so far... BUT:

If I'm having an object from a now and call `$a->getBs();` propel will create a new query. But I thought that I could avoid this query because I already joined B. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `joinWith()`:

```
$as = AQuery::create()
    ->filterByAnyColumn(anyValue)
    ->joinWith('A.B')
    ->find();
```

Details can be found here: [propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html#minimizing-queries](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html#minimizing-queries)